# Undefined symbols error using CocoaLumberjack in Obj-C/Swift project

Tags: swift, objective-c, linker, cocoalumberjack

I have been using CocoaLumberjack painlessly for a while in an objective-C project until recently, while I added some Swift classes into the project and added the following lines to the podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
```

and changed the line that reference the CocoaLumberjack pod from

```
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
```

to:

```
pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
```

The pod install ran successfully. But then I could no longer build the project. Xcode kept complaining:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_DDLogDebug", referenced from:
....
"_DDLogVerbose", referenced from:
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As many other posts online have suggested, I checked the "Linking -> Other Linker Flags" setting under Build Settings and it did already contain the "CocoaLumberjack" item in it.

What might be the problem? Any guidance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the problem was solved after adding the following line to the project's prefix PCH file:

```
#import "CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h"
```